# The position of <EOF> in ANTLR 4 is kind of strange?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I am trying the ANTLR 4, it gives me the following output for the simple `Hello` grammar in the book < The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference >:

```
[@2,12:11='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
```

According to the book's interpretation, the`12:11` notation means `<EOF>` token starts at position `12` and ends at `11`. How could this be possible?

PS. I am working on Windows.

Comment: Maybe its measuring in bytes, using UTF-16 encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ANTLR 4, both endpoints are inclusive. The length of a span with inclusive endpoints is the following:

> Length = End - Start + 1

The length of the EOF symbol is 0 (it appears at a known location, but it contains no input symbols). If the input is 12 characters long, you get this formula for the end position:

> 0 = End - 12 + 1

Therefore:

> End = 0 + 12 - 1 = 11

Comment: Thanks. So I try to understand the motive behind this. My *guess* is, the <EOF> is special because it is just an implicit **conceptual symbol** which doesn't have physical length. ANTLR tries to identify its position while keeping its length as 0. The length of a normal **physical symbol** is calculated as `end-start+1`. And ANTLR wants to keep this formula. So it has to deliberately make the `end less than start by 1` for conceptual symbols like <EOF>. In that way, ANTLR achieves both **zero length for conceptual symbol like <EOF>** and **a universal length formula**.